# In Whitehead and Russell's PM, are overlapping ranges of significance necessarily identical?

Tags: logic, math-history

In  Principia Mathematica summary of ✳63

> In virtue of  ✳20.8, we have
>      $\vdash : \phi a ∨ \sim\phi a . ⊃ . \hat{x}(\phi x \vee \sim \phi x ) =t‘a$
>
> i.e. if "$\phi a$" is significant, then the range of significance of the function $\phi \hat{z} $ is the type of $a$. **It follows that two ranges of significance which overlap are identical, and two different ranges of significance have no member in common.**

Given $T$ is the relation of team mate, then $\overset{→}{T}$ is the relation of team to team member. For example:

Jordan is Pippen's teammate .≡.  (Jordan $.T.$ Pippen),

Chicago Bulls is Jordan's team .≡. (Chicago Bulls) $\overset{→}{T} $ (Jordan)

Chicago Bulls is Pippen's team .≡. (Chicago Bulls) $\overset{→}{T}$ ( Pippen)

$\overset{→}{T} = \hat{\alpha}\hat{y} \{ \alpha = \hat{x}(xTy) \}$

Thus the field of $\overset{→}{T}$ is a class whose members include two types: $C‘\overset{→}{T}$ ={**Chicago Bulls**, Jordan, Pippen, ..., **Lakers**, Bryant, O'Neal...  }

1. let  $\phi(x) = x$ is a basketball player;
2. let $ \psi(\alpha)=\alpha$ is a team;
3. let $\chi(t) = t $ is a member of $C‘\overset{→}{T}$

In the case of #1, $\phi(Jordan)$ is true because Jordan is a basketball player; $\phi(Chicago Bulls)$ is meaningless;

In the case of #2. $\psi(Chicago Bulls)$ is true, but $\psi(Jordan)$ meaningless.

In the case of #3. Both Jordan and Chicago Bulls are members of  $C‘\overset{→}{T}$, thus both $\chi(Jordan)$ and $\chi(ChicagoBulls)$ are true and significant.

Both $\phi{\hat{x}}$'s type and $\psi \hat{\alpha}$'s type overlap with $\chi(\hat{t})$'s type, but none are identical with any other. Thus it appears that two ranges of significance which overlap are not necessarily identical. So, what is wrong with my reasoning?

*I can't emphasize enough of this: At this stage I have no desire to find faults in PM. All I want is to understand PM to the best of my ability*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of $*20.8$ is preceded [see Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, *Principia Mathematica to 56* (2nd ed - 1927), page 198] by a comment that relates the proposition to the *theory of relative types*.

In the same paragraph we have that :

> The "type" of any object $x$ will be defined in $*63$ as the class of terms either identical with $x$ or not identical with $x$. We may define the "type of the arguments to $\phi x$" as the class of arguments $x$ for which "$\phi \hat{z}$" is significant, i.e. the class $\hat{x}(\phi x \lor \sim \phi x$).

Simplifying a lot, we must think at the "universe" as made of "levels" (i.e.*types*) : the "lowest" is that containing the *individuals*; the next one is the level of *classes* of individuals, and so on.

The "range of significance" of a formula $\phi x$ (with $x$ free) **must** be a type.

Following your example, if $t_0$ is the type of basketball players, and if we assume that a team is a class of basketball players, the type of teams will be $t_1$.

Thus, regarding your example :

> > given $T$ is the relation of team mate, then $\overset{→}{T}$ is the relation of team to team member

I think that we have some "restriction" about the ensuing definition :

> $\overset{→}{T} = \hat{\alpha}\hat{y} \{ \alpha = \hat{x}(xTy) \}$,

because I think that we **cannot** have

> "the class whose members include two types".

According to $*32.01$, the $T$-predecessors of $y$ : $\overset{→}{T}‘y = \hat{x}(xTy)$ is, in modern notation : $\{x : xTy \}$.

If we put $\alpha = \overset{→}{T}‘y$, this is a *class*; if we assume $y := Jordan$, this is the class of teammates of Jordan, i.e. the team of Chicago Bulls.

Being a *class*, it is **not** of the same type of Jordan; thus we cannot "predicate" of it the same "predicates" that applies to Jordan.

The relation of "membership" (in modern notation $\in$) is **not** in PM a relation between individuals (or objects of the same type).

It must be defined according to the "criteria" of significance; i.e. $x \in \hat{z} \phi z$ (that I fear is not well-formed in PM language) iff $\phi x$.

All the crux of the matter with the "horrible" PM's theory of types is that you cannot have $\hat{z} \phi z$ at the "same level" of $x$ : if $x$ is of type $t_i$, then every *class* to which $x$ belongs must be of type *at least* $t_{i+1}$.

I think taht the mistake is in the "use" you have done of $\overset{→}{T}$; in the *relation* $T$, both arguments ($x$ and $y$) are players :

> $Jordan .T. Pippen$.

When using $\overset{→}{T}$, we have :

> $Chicago Bulls = \hat{x}(xT Jordan)$

i.e.

> $Chicago Bulls = \overset{→}{T}‘ Jordan$;

but we cannot have :

> $Chicago Bulls .\overset{→}{T}. Jordan$,

because the two "relata" are not of the same type [see Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, *Principia Mathematica to 56* (2nd ed - 1927), page 248].

Comment: See *32.01 for definition of $\overset{→}{R}$

Comment: @GeorgeChen - Ok; but what about the field of $\overline T$ ?

Comment: it's define by *33.3

Comment: $C‘\overset{→}{T} = \hat{x}\{ (∃ y):x\overset{→}{T}y .\vee. y\overset{→}{T}x  \}$

Comment: $C‘R$ is mentioned in *33 summary, first page, two lines above *33.01.

Comment: I think our major point of contention is whether we can have a class with multiple types or not.

Comment: $\overset{→}{R}$ is the relation of all referents to their relatum, e.g. all of Jordan's team mates to Jordan, ie. Chicago bulls to Jordan.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - Ok; I'm seeing in *SEP* the entry on [The Notation in *Principia Mathematica*](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) : I've found : $∗32.01$, called "the $R$-predecessors of y" and $∗33.112$, called "the field of $R$".

Comment: That's correct. 32.01 are referents, but you can call them predecessors if you are dealing with series.

Comment: You got it right, @Mauro. My bad, field relation is defined by *33.03, *33.112 is the descriptive form of 33.03

Comment: At this point, @Mauro, We have only one disagreement: can a class have members of different types?

Comment: $ \overset{→}{R}$ is a relation between **the** class of referents(predecessors) and the relatum. If R is child to father, then $\overset{→}{R}‘David$ the class of all of David's children.

Comment: Chicago Bulls $= \overset{→}{T}‘Jordan$, thus both Chicago Bulls and Jordan are members of the field of $\overset{→}{T}$.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - you are right about $\overline R$ : it "selects" a *class* : $\overline R ‘David$ is the class of all of David's children. But it is **not** a relation...Thus, your definition : $\overline T = \hat{\alpha} \hat{y} \{ α = \hat{x} (xTy) \}$ sounds wrong to me ... In modern notation, we have simply : $\alpha_y = \{ x : xTy \}$ i.e. $\alpha_y = \hat{x} (xTy)$.

Comment: I know there must be something wrong with my reasoning, but *32.01 defined $\overset{→}{R}$ as a relation. and if it is a relation, it must have a field which, in this case, includes both classes and individuals as members.

Comment: aha, found it. You're right @Mauro, $C‘\overset{→}{T}$ is meaning less. It's one page 261, second page of *33

Comment: "Thus, for example, if R is a homogeneous relation,$\overset{\rightarrow}{R}$  and $\overset{\leftarrow}{R}$ are not homogeneous, and therefore $C‘\overset{\leftarrow}{R}$ and $C‘\overset{\rightarrow}{R}$" are meaningless." -- page 261 first paragraph, 1st ed.

Comment: The relation $\overset{\rightarrow}{R}$ exists. It just doesn't have a field class.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - thanks !

Comment: Thank you @Mauro. It would probably take me months to figure that out alone.